# How to format brackets of nested JSON

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create a string which holds JSON data.  I'm having an issue formatting the inner nested data, it currently has square brackets '[]' and I'm trying to change it to '{}', so it is valid JSON.    Are there better approaches/solutions to parsing this data?

Actual Results:

```
[
    [
        "eventtime":"2019-09-20 09:52:47",
        "keyid":"15",
    ], 
    [
        "eventtime":"2019-09-20 09:52:47",
        "keyid":"15",
    ]
]
```

Desired Results

```
[
    {
        "eventtime":"2019-09-20 09:52:47",
        "keyid":"15",
    }, 
    {
        "eventtime":"2019-09-20 09:52:47",
        "keyid":"15",
    }
]
```

Code

```
    // Parse and loop through the JSON
    for (NSDictionary * dataDict in eventArray) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        eventTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"eventtime\":\"",[self eventTimeConversion:[dataDict objectForKey:@"event_time"]]];
        keyID =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"keyid\":\"",[dataDict objectForKey:@"key_id"]];
        editTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"edittime\":\"",[self eventTimeConversion:[dataDict objectForKey:@"event_time"]]];
        projectID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"projectid\":\"",[gotHeaders objectAtIndex:0]];
        lockID =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"doorid\":\"",[dataDict objectForKey:@"lock_id"]];
        eventType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"eventid\":\"",[dataDict objectForKey:@"event_type"]];

        [array addObject:eventTime];
        [array addObject:keyID];
        [array addObject:editTime];
        [array addObject:projectID];
        [array addObject:lockID];
        [array addObject:eventType];

        [event_array  addObject:array];
    }
}

NSData *jsonnData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:event_array options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *eventsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: `[ ... ]` and `{ ... }` are different things in JSON. Put the stuff into a dictionary, not an array and try that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is home task question.

Comment: @Cy-4AH "home task question", would you be so kind as to give me the English translation? cheers

Comment: Looks like I have forgot about article. A home task question. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a JSON string *manually*, create dictionaries, this is a simplified example for the keys `eventtime` and `keyid`

The code uses modern Objective-C syntax (introduced at least 6 years ago)

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary * dataDict in eventArray) {
    NSString *eventTime = [self eventTimeConversion: dataDict[@"event_time"]];
    NSString *keyID = dataDict[@"key_id"];
    [array addObject:@{@"eventtime":eventTime, @"keyid":keyID}];
}
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonnData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: array options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *eventsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an array to store the JSON id and value parameters, use a `NSDictionary`:

```
NSDictionary *d1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"eventtime", @"2019-09-20 09:52:47",
                    @"keyid", @"15", nil];
[event_array  addObject:d1];

...

NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:event_array 
                    options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *eventsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", eventsString);
```

You will need to obviously replace the hardcoded values I have put on the dictionary in the example with your values.

This will output:

```
[
    {
        "eventtime":"2019-09-20 09:52:47",
        "keyid":"15",
    }, 
    {
        "eventtime":"2019-09-20 09:52:47",
        "keyid":"15",
    }
]
```